# How to drop 3 levels with react router ei. path='.../file'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, path, react-router

Currently I am using a React Router to route different paths to different react components. I have the following example code:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/profile/viewmessage/:message">
        <Profile />
    </Route>
    <Route path=".../friends">
        <Friends />
    </Route>
<Switch>
```

*EDIT: This code will result in a path: "/profile/viewmessage/message/.../friends" if left with the .../friends path.*
You can't have the path simply be "/friends" because then the path will actually be "/profile/message/friends" if you are trying to view a message.
 You can't use path="../friends" because then the overall path will be "/profile/friends".
 I know there has to be a way to overcome, this I just haven't been able to find one online. Is there a nice way of dropping several levels. 
Thanks in advance. Any pointers in the right direction to do this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, this was an unfortunate question... 
Apparently all you have to do is drop to the exact path you want having the path="/friends" for example including the full path.
So if you had "/page/view/select/message" and you wanted to drop to the view section you would set path="/page/view"
you must include the prefix "/" or it will not drop to the level you want (which is the problem I had).

To fix the problem I had all you have to do is give the path the full path to where you want to navigate with a preceding "/".

the correct code would have been:

```
<Switch>
<Route path="/profile/viewmessage/:message">
    <Profile />
</Route>
<Route path="/friends">
    <Friends />
</Route>
```

Again this works because of the preceding /. if the path had been just "friends" then it would append that to the current path. Such a simple answer.